# Asks for Account Type twice

Tags: c++

Been working on this program for a while now. (had some problems and asked a few times here.) Ran into another one though! The program asks for my account type twice. Can not figure out why or how to fix it. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
    /*
project3.cpp
Andre Fecteau
CSC135-101
October 29, 2013
This program prints a bank's service fees per month depending on account type
*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/*
Basic Function for Copy Paste
<function type> <function name> (){

// Declarations
// Initalizations
// Input
// Process
// Output
// Prolouge
}
*/

void displayInstructions (){
// Declarations
// Initalizations
// Input
// Process
// Output
cout <<"| -------------------------------------------------------------- |" << endl;
cout <<"| ---------- Welcome to the bank fee calculator ---------------- |" << endl;
cout <<"| -------------------------------------------------------------- |" << endl;
cout <<"| This Program wil ask you to eneter your account number.        |" << endl;
cout <<"| Then it will ask for your account type Personal or Commercial. |" << endl;
cout <<"| Then ask for the amount of checks you have written.            |" << endl;
cout <<"| Lastly it will output how much your fees are for this month.   |" << endl;
cout <<"| -------------------------------------------------------------- |" << endl;
cout << endl;
// Prolouge
}

int readAccNumb(){
  // delarations
  int accNumber;
  // intitalizations
  accNumber = 0.0;
  // input
  cout << "Please Enter Account Number:";
  cin >> accNumber;
  // Procesas
  // output
  // prolouge
  return accNumber;
}

int checksWritten (){
// Declarations
int written;
// Initalizations
written = 0.0;
// Input
cout <<"Please input the amount of checks you have written this month:";
cin >> written;
// Output
// Prolouge
return written;
}

char accType (){
// Declarations
char answer;
int numberBySwitch;
// Initalizations
numberBySwitch = 1;
// Input
while (numberBySwitch == 1){
    cout << "Please Enter the acount type (C for Comerical and P for Personal):";
    cin >> answer;
// Process
switch (answer){
    case 'p':
        answer = 'P';
        numberBySwitch += 2;break;
    case 'P':
        numberBySwitch += 2;break;
    case 'c':
        answer = 'C';
        numberBySwitch += 3;break;
    case 'C':
        numberBySwitch += 3;break;
    default:
        if(numberBySwitch == 1) {
        cout << "Error! Please enter a correct type!" <<endl;
        }
    }
}
// Output
// Prolouge
return answer;
}

int commericalCalc(int checksWritten){
// Declarations
int written;
int checkPrice;
// Initalizations
checkPrice = 0.0;
// Input
// Process
if(written < 20){
    checkPrice = 0.10;
}
// Output
// Prolouge
return checkPrice;
}

int personalCalc(int checksWritten){

}

double pricePerCheck(char accType, int checksWritten){
// Declarations
double price;
char answer;
// Initalizations
price = 0.0;
// Input
// Process
if(accType == 'P'){
}
if(accType == 'C'){
    if(checksWritten < 20){
        price = 0.10;
    }
}
// Output
// Prolouge
return price;
}

int main(){
  // Declarations
  int accountNumb;
  char theirAccType;
  int writtenChecks;
  double split;
  // Initalizations
  accountNumb = 0.0;
  writtenChecks = 0.0;
  split = 0.0;
  theirAccType = ' ';
  // Input
  displayInstructions();
  theirAccType = accType();
  accountNumb = readAccNumb();
  split = pricePerCheck(accType(), checksWritten());
  // Output
cout << endl;
cout << "Account Type: " << theirAccType << endl;
cout << "Check Price: " << split << endl;
  // Prolouge
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
theirAccType = accType();
...
split = pricePerCheck(accType(), checksWritten());
//                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

You're calling `accType` for the second time. You should be passing in the variable that you used to hold the initial call on the first line.

```
split = pricePerCheck(theirAccType, checksWritten());
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: It's important to understand *why* it worked - `accType() is a function that returns a value. You assigned that value to be `theirAccType`. So when you want to call `pricePerCheck`, you need to pass *that value* instead of calling `accType()` again as you did (before you fixed the issue). Another way to implement this would be to call `accType()` directly when you call `pricePerCheck` (as you had originally), and then **don't** call it the first time (assigning to *theirAccType*. As @0x499602D2 pointed out, you called it twice. You only needed to call it once ;)

Answer (score 0):

The request for account type is made in the `accType()` function. You're calling that function twice in this code:

```
 displayInstructions();
  theirAccType = accType();
  accountNumb = readAccNumb();
  split = pricePerCheck(accType(), checksWritten());
```

`accType()` is called to assign the value to `theirAccType`, and again as an argument to `pricePerCheck()`.

You probably need

```
  split = pricePerCheck(theirAccType, checksWritten());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `pricePerCheck()` you pass the result of calling `accType()` rather than `theirAccType`: you stored the result of the first call but you are making a second call. C++ doesn't memoize the result of function calls.

BTW, you want to compile your code with a higher warning level! There are number of fatal issues in your code:

1. `personalCalc()` is declared to return an `int` but doesn't return anything (the function isn't call, though, i.e. your question, obviously, isn't a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).
2. The function `commericalCalc()` uses the the value of an uninitialized variable (`written`). It seems to be also badly named.

Comment: the personalCalc and the commericalCalc may be left over from when I tried another method. I will make sure to remove them if they aren't used. Do you know how to add a higher warning level in Code::blocks?

Comment: @AndréFecteau: I'm not using Code::blocks (never got to use an IDE...). I think Code::blocks may use gcc under the hood. If you are using gcc enable `-W -Wall`.